# How to get the list of IP address in 2nd LAN network in python

Tags: python, networking

I'm trying to get the IP addresses of Local Area Connection 2 in Windows.

First, I run a batch file that registers set of IP address

```
192.168.254.214
192.168.253.91
192.168.129.1
192.168.254.104
```

I'd like to check if those IP address was registered successfully using python. I've tried searching on how to get the IP address in a specific network interfaces but the answers is not the answers I'm expecting.

Question:

> I'd like to know if the IP address in the batch file was successfully registered in Local Area Connection 2?

Thank you for help!

Comment: you didn't describe the question clearly, what is your input and what do you expect?

Comment: @armnotstrong Hi, oh I'm sorry. I'd like to find out if the list of IP address is successfully registered in Local Area Connection 2.

Comment: have you tried `psutil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this to get the IP address

```
import socket
ips=[i[4][0] for i in socket.getaddrinfo(socket.gethostname(), None)]
```

and then you could compare the result with the IP list you give

Note: have tested that on windows 7

Comment: Wow!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Another information for this, this will get all the IPs in the computer. Anyway this will help! Thank you again! @armnotstrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [arp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) request and parse results with the regular expression. I suppose it's most efficient way to solve that problem. You can find the code on StackOverflow.